# The meaning of freq(w) in JCN similarity

Tags: similarity, wordnet

I want to calculate the wordnet jcn similarity of each class in Imagenet classes tree. According to the article they referenced, the frequency of a class c is [the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp0eK.png)

In my understanding, it's the sum of the word/class the class c contains. But it seems wrong when I compare my result with other people's. So I wonder how to implement it.